# TextMorph default font size

Tags: squeak

I'm trying to have an empty TextMorph with a default font size of 12 points, where the original default is 9pts. If I bring up the halo and change the font size to 12pts, the empty TextMorph will still default to 9pts when text is entered into it. I can sort of get around this by putting a space in the TextMorph, then changing the font via the halo to be 12pts. However, this seems rather clunky, and as such was wondering if there might be another way to accomplish this?

thanks.

Comment: Which version of Squeak are you using?